# Twitter clone with API similar to Twitter?

Tags: api, twitter

As we all know, Twitter consistently has problems keeping their service up and running.

There are literally dozens of Twitter clones out there.  Does anybody know of a Twitter clone with an API that is as similar as possible to Twitter's API as possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

**[identi.ca](http://identi.ca)** is twitter clone based in the opensource **[status.net](http://status.net)** solution with a twitter-compatible API: http://status.net/wiki/API

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at identi.ca:

http://status.net/wiki/TwitterCompatibleAPI

Answer (score 1):

Now that microblogging has been around for a while, there are some other options than http://status.net (previously http://laconi.ca).

- Floopo

There are probably more, but this is the first I'd seen - try googling for "microblogging twitter clones" if you haven't yet.